# Grails resources plugin and cloudfoundry

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, cloud-foundry

I tried to deploy my app to cloudfoundry, everything goes smooth however none of my static resources that use the resources plugin can be found.

In the logs i get lots of errors like the below

> 2012-01-31 13:36:41,352 [http-46220-3] WARN  util.ResourceMetaStore  -
>   Cannot locate resource [/static/css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css]

I first thought that this is due to cloudfoundry not having any disk space allocated but based on this thread it should work out of the box

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Cloud-foundry-and-resources-plugin-with-js-css-td4243619.html

The test application i am running is running on one instance and i am using version 1.1.6 of the resources plugin.

Anybody else experiencing similar problems?

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of the resources plugin. Some issues similar to this one were resolved recently. I can deploy on CF using Grails 2.0.0 and resources plugin 1.1.6

Comment: Yes i have Grails 2.0.0 and resources plugin 1.1.6 also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are not missing the following line in your Config.groovy

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was the solution

Comment: This seem to fix my problem when the grails app is deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem on heroku platform. It seems that problem is related with resources plugin and load balancing. My be the following will be useful:

[Heroku, Grails: Missing resources if using multiple web dynos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881978/heroku-grails-missing-resources-if-using-multiple-web-dynos)

Comment: Tried to create an artifact for my resources but it did not make any difference, I am only running on one instance on CF so i should not experience similar load-balancing problems as you.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm 100% that this works in "production" environment locally?

Comment: This works very fine on my local apache-tomcat instance.
I also tested by running grails prod run-app.
Both work perfectly fine

Comment: I Also tried with a completely new app from scratch. And that one works fine on cloudfoundry
However my real app is using a couple of other plugins. I am starting to wonder if something could be conflicting there. None of the plugins is direclty related to the resources plugin though. and still why wouldnt it just not work on cloudfoundry?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Grails 2.0 application on Cloud Foundry (http://tripplanner-ali.cloudfoundry.com/trip/create). It is using the resources plugin (1.1.5) along with cloud-support and cloud-foundry and jquery of course. I would suggest you to have your STS setup with Grails 2.0 if you haven't done so and try to create a sample application and deploy it to CF. Here is where you can get STS with Grails 2.0 working (http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/2.7.0/reference/html/grails/grails20.html).

Once you have this setup, All you have to do is create a new Grails project and you will get the resources plugin along with jquery by default.